# How can I access a “property” by the name, given as a string?

Tags: oop, lua

I'm trying to build some objects in Lua. I found http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectProperties, and http://lua-users.org/wiki/SimpleLuaClasses, which allowed me to build:

```
package.path = "../src/?.lua;" .. package.path
require("class")

Feeds = {}
Feeds.__index = Feeds

-- Make proxy object with property support.
-- Notes:
--   If key is found in <getters> (or <setters>), then
--     corresponding function is used, else lookup turns to the
--     <class> metatable (or first to <priv> if <is_expose_private> is true).
--   Given a proxy object <self>, <priv> can be obtained with
--     getmetatable(self).priv .
-- @param class - metatable acting as the object class.
-- @param priv - table containing private data for object.
-- @param getters - table of getter functions
--                  with keys as property names. (default is nil)
-- @param setters - table of setter functions,
--                  with keys as property names. (default is nil)
-- @param is_expose_private - Boolean whether to expose <priv> through proxy.
--                  (default is nil/false)
-- @version 3 - 20060921 (D.Manura)
local function make_proxy(class, priv, getters, setters, is_expose_private)
  setmetatable(priv, class)  -- fallback priv lookups to class
  local fallback = is_expose_private and priv or class
  local index = getters and
    function(self, key)
      -- read from getter, else from fallback
      local func = getters[key]
      if func then return func(self) else return fallback[key] end
    end
    or fallback  -- default to fast property reads through table
  local newindex = setters and
    function(self, key, value)
      -- write to setter, else to proxy
      local func = setters[key]
      if func then func(self, value)
      else rawset(self, key, value) end
    end
    or fallback  -- default to fast property writes through table
  local proxy_mt = {         -- create metatable for proxy object
    __newindex = newindex,
    __index = index,
    priv = priv
  }
  local self = setmetatable({}, proxy_mt)  -- create proxy object
  return self
end

function Feeds:new(...)
   local names = {
      "material",
      "diameter",
      "flutes",
      "pass_depth",
      "stepover",
      "entry",
      "aggressiveness",
      "spindle_speed",
      "feedrate",
      "entry_rate",
      "sec_per_in",
      "delta_t",
      "feed_better",
      "hp",
      "hp_percent",
      "deflection",
      "defl_percent",
      "mrr",
      "surface_speed",
      "chipload"}
   local rv = {}
   local p
   for i, v in ipairs(...) do
      if i <= #names then
--        print("for ".. i .. "\t" .. names[i] .. ": "..v)
        rv[names[i]] = v
      end
   end
  return make_proxy(Feeds, rv, Feeds_getters, Feeds_setters) 
end


local Feeds_attribute_setters = {
  material = function(self, material)
    local priv = getmetatable(self).priv
    assert(type(material) == "string")
    priv.material = material
  end
}

local Feeds_getters = {
  b = function(self, value)
    local priv = getmetatable(self).priv
    return priv.a
  end
}
```

Unlike the simple examples on the above web pages (a single parameter, called `a` that's set to 5.), I have an object that takes 20 positional parameters. (They're columns from a spreadsheet.) The names of these parameters are shown as the local `names`.

The parameters seem to be set properly, with the value passed in associated with the corresponding name in the `priv` variable.

The problem is in accessing the class fields. If `name` is the variable containing the name of the desired parameter, I need to be able to get the associated value.

```
    actual = Feeds:new(arg)
    print("name= " .. actual.name)
```

This doesn't work because (I think) `.name` is supposed to be accessing the field called `name`. If `name="material"`, I want to get the value for value of `name`, which is `material` and the parameter `material`'s value, `"MDF"`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `actual[name]`. `actual.name` is a syntax sugar for `actual["name"]`, so you can pass a variable (`name` in your case) instead of a literal value.